# Spark 3.2 keeps showing Running state

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I run a WordCount using Spark3.2 + Hadoop 2.7,but the log keeps showing Runng state like

```
22/02/05 17:31:22 INFO Client: Application report for application_1643188585145_0090 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/02/05 17:31:23 INFO Client: Application report for application_1643188585145_0090 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/02/05 17:31:24 INFO Client: Application report for application_1643188585145_0090 (state: RUNNING)
22/02/05 17:31:24 INFO Client:
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: XXX06XXXXX
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 40135
     queue: MYQUEUE
     start time: 1644053471894
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: MYURL/application_1643188585145_0090/
     user: MYUSER
22/02/05 17:31:25 INFO Client: Application report for application_1643188585145_0090 (state: RUNNING)
22/02/05 17:31:26 INFO Client: Application report for application_1643188585145_0090 (state: RUNNING)
22/02/05 17:31:27 INFO Client: Application report for application_1643188585145_0090 (state: RUNNING)
...
endless RUNNING
```

i change the log level to debug, then it shows

note: URL1(IP1) is my one of my two Resources Managers which I changed nothing with

```
22/02/06 14:20:44 INFO Client: Application report for application_1643188585145_0111 (state: RUNNING)
22/02/06 14:20:45 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (527211736) connection to URL1/IP1:8832 from MYUSER sending #738
22/02/06 14:20:45 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (527211736) connection to URL1/IP1:8832 from MYUSER got value #738
22/02/06 14:20:45 DEBUG ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: getApplicationReport took 1ms
22/02/06 14:20:45 INFO Client: Application report for application_1643188585145_0111 (state: RUNNING)
22/02/06 14:20:46 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (527211736) connection to URL1/IP1:8832:8832 from MYUSER sending #739
22/02/06 14:20:46 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (527211736) connection to URL1/IP1:8832:8832 from MYUSER got value #739
22/02/06 14:20:46 DEBUG ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: getApplicationReport took 2ms
22/02/06 14:20:46 INFO Client: Application report for application_1643188585145_0111 (state: RUNNING)
```

I deploy spark-3.2.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz in my cluster
and follow https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/running-on-yarn.html#configuring-the-external-shuffle-service  which contains steps blow to configure  shuffle service:

```
1.upload yarn-shuffle.jar to /home/yarn/software/lib4yarn/hdfs/ of all NodeMangers
2.set /home/yarn/software/hadoop/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml referring the docs
3.set YARN_HEAPSIZE=2000 in /home/yarn/software/hadoop/etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh 
4.restart all NodeManagers
```

then submit a wordcount

```
$SPARK32/bin/spark-submit --master yarn \
--deploy-mode client  --class WordCount \
--num-executors=5 --executor-cores=2 --executor-memory=2G 
MY_WordCount.jar
```

[Yarn HomePage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUwsI.png)

[the app page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9klnn.png)

[Spark UI: stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bizYn.png)

[Spark UI: executors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5omfz.png)

Comment: Show the yarn UI

Comment: Hi  @OneCricketeer ， i uploaded some pics

Comment: You might want to look into the 7 unhealthy nodes YARN reports, but looks like the Spark driver hasn't been allocated any resources (cores=0) also the few Spark jobs before have all finished but failed. What errors did they show?

Comment: Yes, the key problem is no resources is allocated. The 7 unhealthy nodes don't play any role in the cluster and the nodes remain have enough resources.

Comment: I remove the yarn-shuffle.jar, keep the config of yarn-site.xml (because it already has before I use spark 3.2), then I submit the job with --jars., something strange happens:  
1. --deploy mode client --jars THE.jar  ----conf spark.{driver|executor}.extraClassPath=THE.jar   【many executors are allocated but still stuck like (0/2)(1 running) 】
2.--deploy mode cluster  -jars THE.jar  ----conf spark.{driver.executor}.extraClassPath=THE.jar  【no executor is allocated and stuck like (0/2)， not a  job is running】
3. --deploy mode cluster|client  with no THE.jar, it finishes successfully